# how to not let a user open any other users page?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5.2, ruby-on-rails-6

In my app, when a user logins he/she is redirected to the users profile page. Say he/she is redirected to http://localhost:3000/users/1

If he/she replaces 1 with any other number I want them to redirect to there
current profile no matter if users exits in the database or not

```
 class SessionsController < ApplicationController
  def new
  end

 def create
  user = User.find_by_email(params[:email])
  if user && user.authenticate(params[:password])
    log_in user
    redirect_to user
  else
    flash.now[:danger] = 'Invalid email/password combination'
    render 'new'
  end
end

 def destroy
  @current_user = nil
  reset_session
  redirect_to root_path
end
```

end

User Controller:

```
  class UsersController < ApplicationController
     before_action :logged_in_user, only: [:new, :show, :edit, :update]
     before_action :correct_user, only: [:new, :show, :edit, :update]


 def index
  @users = User.all
 end

 def new
   @user = User.new
 end

 def create
   @user = User.new(set_params)
  if @user.save
    redirect_to new_sessions_path
  else
    render 'new'
  end
end

 def show
   @user = User.find(params[:id])
   @posts = @user.posts
 end

 def edit
   @user = User.find(params[:id])
  end

def update
  @user = User.find(params[:id])
  if @user.update(update_params)
    redirect_to @user
  else
    render 'edit'
 end
end

private

def set_params
  params.require(:user).permit(:name, :email, :password, :password_confirmation)
end

def update_params
  params.require(:user).permit(:name, :email, :password, :password_confirmation)
end 

  def correct_user
    @user = User.find(params[:id])
    redirect_to(root_url) unless current_user?(@user)
 end

 end
```

Currenty if user type in search bar localhost:3000/users/5 and user with id 5 does not exists in database it shows error

**ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound in UsersController#show
Couldn't find User with 'id'=3**

but I want to simply redirect to currently logged in users profile page.

If users type in search bar localhost:3000/users/3 and user with this id exists in db , currenty it show an error that firefox is not able to process this request but i want it redirect to its default page i.e,,user's profile page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just change your `UsersController#correct_user` to catch ActiveRecord NotFound exception:

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController
  ...

  def correct_user
    @user = User.find(params[:id])
    redirect_to(root_url) unless current_user?(@user)
  rescue ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound
    redirect_to(root_url)
  end

end
```

Comment: Note that as written this solution doesn't redirect an incorrect user. It's also probably a good idea to use a non-throwing methods such as `find_by` instead of relying on exceptions in this case.

Comment: @AndrewSchwartz Thank you for correction. I've fix an answer.

Answer (score 1):

Create another controller call it UserController and don't depend on **id**. Instead figure out the **current user from the session** and display that user. So the show method for this controller would look like this:

```
 def show
   @user = User.find(session["user_id]")
   @posts = @user.posts
 end
```

Also, you might want to protect your UsersController by validating if the current user has access to view / update the user being queried for.

Answer (score 0):

I would use "where" and ".take" in Users show method. The find method brakes the code when it does not find anything

```
def show 
 @user = User.where("id" => params[:id]).take
 if @user.present? 
  @posts = @user.posts
 else
  redirect_to(root_url)
 end
end
```

Or you can redirect instead of root_url to a more friendly error view that shows User not found